# Configure kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I've been at this task for days now. I've been looking everywhere else for answers but I just can't seem to find one. I'm trying to configure a blank dashboard for Kibana. When I try to click on the configure button, there's nothing happening. Literally nothing. I don't know where I've messed it up. There are no errors, at least not that I'm aware of. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you look at the Developer Tools console?

Comment: If you have Chrome, press F12 and then click over Console. If you use Firefox, download http://getfirebug.com/. In the console, there should be an error description that can help you to debug your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can start with a clean/empty dashboard through a link like `http://yourhost/kibana/index.html#/dashboard/file/blank.json`